# Want to show the video by jquery but click event doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to show an video by using click event, but the click event doesn't trigger.

Here is the code:

```
<div id="video-section">
    <div class="radial-progress">
        <div class="r-circle">
            <div class="mask full">
                <div class="fill"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="mask half">
                <div class="fill"></div>
                <div class="fill fix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="inset">
            <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/92371445"></iframe>
</div>  <!-- end video-section -->
```

And this is my jquery codes

```
$('#video-section .radial-progress').on('click', function() {
  $('#video-section > iframe').show();
});
```

You can see my **[live example here](http://codepen.io/thehung1724/pen/qENVpJ)**, it doesn't works for showing video.

**Updated**: I fixed myself. What happened is when I put the code in the last js file, there is another js get errors so it can't load this code. I also added a little code to make it play when play button is clicked.

Comment: jQuery is not loaded in your Pen. That's why.

Comment: You also need to correct the iframe src.

Comment: Thank @Terry In my project, I already loaded in my page first but I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: You'll need the vimeo js API to get the video to play. All your code does is unhide the iframe. http://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api

Comment: http://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api did not work in Firefox on Mac, but worked fine in Safari and Chrome.

Comment: @FunkDoc I don't know why it doesn't work on localhost, then I copied all code to Pen and it works.